# What is Chinese word for nostil flaring?

Tags: word-requests

Straightforward question. I want to say that I can do a nostril flaring or I can nostril-flare. Googling this pointed to the flare that caused by a disease or kind of that but here I can do it normally so it's a genetic inheritance. Is there a verb word for it in Chinese?

Comment: Might need to explain it - not even sure what you're referring to.

Comment: I think the response below nailed it. Where is the poster? Please accept it or explain your question further.

Answer (score 2):

Google Translate: [Nostril flaring --> 鼻孔擴張](https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=zh-TW&text=nostril-flare&op=translate)

And [this site](https://www.mountsinai.org/health-library/symptoms/nasal-flaring) agrees:

> Nasal flaring (鼻孔擴張) occurs when the nostrils widen while breathing. It is often a sign of trouble breathing.

"Nostrils flaring" (鼻孔擴張) is a symptom that happens involuntarily; someone who makes his nostrils widen voluntarily should be called "to flare nostrils" (擴張鼻孔)

[image]

Nostrils can also be translated as 鼻翼

Answer (score 0):

emmm, this is really an interesting question. The straightforward translation is "鼻孔扩张". However, I have never heard anyone said that, I guess you would like a more common-used phrase. What I realized is that I never expressed it in mandarin and I can't think of any word conforming to nostril-flare in mandarin.

What an intriguing thing is there is a phrase in my dialect meaning "nostril-flare". The pronunciation is like "xiu bie de". My dialect belongs to Wu Dialect. But I don't know whether each type of Wu Dialect has such an expression.

By the way, I can nostril-flare as well.